# Code Crashing Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, crash

This script crashes firefox and brings up unresponsive script message at the line of code with `blueSelectorBar[mobIndex].style.border = "3px solid white"`

Here is the section of script

```
        var blueSelectorBar = document.getElementById('blueSelector').getElementsByTagName('div');
        for (var bar = 0; bar < blueSelectorBar.length; bar++){
            var blueCurrentBox = blueSelectorBar[bar];
            console.log(blueCurrentBox.dataset.mob)
            var blueMobId = blueCurrentBox.dataset.mob
            if (eval(blueMobId) == toReturn){
                var mobIndex = bar
                for (var bar2 = 0; bar2 < blueSelectorBar.length; bar++){
                    blueSelectorBar[bar2].style.border = "3px solid black"
                };
            };
        };
        blueSelectorBar[mobIndex].style.border = "3px solid white"
        return toReturn
```

Why is it crashing?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing with `eval()` there, but there's likely to be a much better way of getting the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the inner loop:

```
            for (var bar2 = 0; bar2 < blueSelectorBar.length; bar++){
                blueSelectorBar[bar2].style.border = "3px solid black"
            };
```

you're incrementing `bar` instead of `bar2`. Thus that loop will never finish because `bar2` never changes.

Comment: @icantmakegoodquestionsapparent please mark this as the answer.